# How to show fragment as a dialog?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have developed application in which I want to display Fragment as a dialog,

I used Tabs and Fragment in my  application, I have just one activity and I replace the fragment as I need,

If we used activity then we declare "android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" in Manifest file to display activity as dialog, same thing I want to do for Fragment

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout Use a DialogFragment.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Answer (score 10):

We can show a Fragment as a dialog using two means , but a single way.

Explanation:

Way:

Extend class  DialogFragment  and override any one of two methods:

onCreateView() OR

onCreateDialog().

**Diff. between these two:**

Overriding **onCreateView**() will let you show a Fragment as dialog and you can make the Title text customized.

On the other hand, overriding **onCreateDialog**(),  you can again show a fragment as dialog and here you can customize the entire dialog fragment. Means, you can inflate any view to show as dialog.

If you need any source code explaining the above text, let me know.

**Note:**

Using DialogFragment has a disadvantage. It doesn't handle screen orientation. And crashes the app.

So, you need to use setRetainInstance() inside onCreate() of DialogFragment class.

Comment: I disagree with your note on orientation changes. I have used DialogFragment multiple times and it works fine when changing orientation. Obviously it will be recreated, like all fragments, when you change orientation.

Comment: @FabianStreitel : Pls check, if setRetainInstance() method has been used in onCreate() in your code, or some other mean to avoid the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a DialogFragment. It is the intended fragment subclass for this use..
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a loading dialog that I use:

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class LoadingDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private final String message;

    private LoadingDialogFragment(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public static LoadingDialogFragment newInstance(String message) {
        LoadingDialogFragment fragment = new LoadingDialogFragment(message);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage(message);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        return dialog;
    }

}
```

Can be instantiated like this:

```
 LoadingDialogFragment.newInstance(context.getString(R.string.loading_message))
```

You can inflate views and setContentView from inside of this dialog if you want a custom layout.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

Comment: I used DialogFragment , but it still display as a front, not like a dialog, can you give me a link for sample demo

Comment: This is how I show a fragment from the above: LoadingDialogFragment.newInstance(context.getString(R.string.loading_message)).show(getFragmentManager(), "searchingDialog");

Comment: @Jayesh what do you mean it "displays as a front"? I don't understand. A dialog will always be displayed on top of the activity. If you want to change the contents of the fragment you can set your own layout in onCreateDialog. Please clarify :/

Comment: means I have a five tabs in application, when I click on button of second fragment (set for second tab) , a new fragment should be shown as a dialog then no one tabs can be clicked, got the point ?

I want to do same as activity and I don't need message or anything, I have a xml that i want to show in dialogfragment.

Answer (score -3):

Your fragment class should extend DialogFragment rather than fragment.

Check out the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html